# How to add column header to a math multiplication table using for loops

Tags: java

I am trying to get a header put on top of a multiplication table. So the user can input 3x3 and it will look like

```
   1 2 3
   _ _ _
1| 1 2 3
2| 2 4 6
3| 3 6 9
```

I am able to get the left hand side but I am having trouble trying to get the top part. Anyone have any thought how I can get those to show up?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int columns, rows;

// getting the inputs
System.out.println("Please enter the amount of columns you want for your table!");
columns = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of rows you want for your table!");
rows = keyboard.nextInt();

// creating the table

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%d |", i);

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
    }
}

System.out.println("\n");
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far

Comment: "Code snippet" is meant for HTML/JS/CSS code examples so don't use them for Java code. Use "Code Sample" (`Ctrl`+`K`) for Java code.

Comment: that makes sense. I will know that for next time. Thanks!

Comment: You already have a loop that prints `columns.` Copy this twice to outside the `rows` loop. Once with printing `i.` Once with printing '_'. Print "␣␣" before each of them.

Comment: System.out.printf("%5d" , i);
System.out.println("_"); something like this?

Comment: @Brando Each of them inside the appropriate of the two loops, yes. But with `print(...)` rather than `println(...)` at the latter to omit newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at the table loop.  A row is a row, is a row <del>your boat, gently down the io stream...</del>

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%d |", i);

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
    }
}
```

Assuming `rows` is 3 and `columns` is 3, this will point out:

```
1 |    1    2    3
2 |    2    4    6
3 |    3    6    9
```

What you are asking about is printing the results to look more like:

```
       1    2    3
       _    _    _
1 |    1    2    3
2 |    2    4    6
3 |    3    6    9
```

Note that the header row is *very* similar to the first row of the results.

One could then extract the loop for this row and run it first.

```
System.out.print("   "); // spacing for the column
for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%5d", j); // don't need a i * j when i is 1.
}

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%d |", i);

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
    }
}
```

This gets us part of the way there...

```
       1    2    3
1 |    1    2    3
2 |    2    4    6
3 |    3    6    9
```

But it lacks the header separator.

For this, we would need another indent, and then the associated separator.  As each column takes up five spaces (the `%5d`), this would look something like:

```
System.out.print("   "); // spacing for the column
for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%5d", j); // don't need a i * j when i is 1.
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("   "); // spacing for the column
for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
    System.out.print("    -"); // print text instead of numbers
    //                12345
}

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%d |", i);

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great! thank you so much for the help. It really makes sense now. I was trying to do it in the same loop as the table. But  making it print out before hand makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `"%3d |"` to print row numbers, which uses 5 characters (3 for digits, 1 space, 1 `|`), so your header needs to be moved 5 characters to left. You can do it by printing 5 spaces before you start printing each column number, so code for printing columns headers can look like.

```
System.out.print("     ");
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%5d",i);
}
System.out.println();
```

Now to print `___________________` under your column headers you need to

- print 5 spaces at start to move this line under column numbers, and not above rows numbers,
- and after it print `N` times (where N represents number of columns) string with containing 5 `_` (because each column takes 5 characters as described in `%5d"` formatter).

So code for this task can look like

```
System.out.print("     ");
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.print("_____");//you can use `" ____"` if you want to split this line
}
System.out.println();
```

Now try to add these code snippets before you will print your array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I was trying to do it in the same loop as the table. But doing it before the table makes a lot of since! thanks!!!